# CKAN Joining resources and datasets

Tags: ckan

I'm looking for an easy way to create / explore / view new datasets. This datasets are just the result of an inner join between join compatible resources.

Take for instance dataset A:

```
year, debt
2010, 1000
2011, 900
2012, 800
```

And dataset B:

```
year, earnings
2010, 20000
2011, 18000
2012, 23000
```

I would like to dinamically be able to explore the dataset A join B:

```
year, earnings, debt
2010, 1000, 20000
2011, 900, 18000
2012, 800, 23000
```

I have checked in the [extensions website](http://extensions.ckan.org) but couldn't find anything.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a SQL query that joins the tables by passing it to the `datastore_search_sql` API, which is documented here:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_search_sql